# mac eclipse and version control

Tags: eclipse, macos, version-control, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for an svn client and host that I can easily set up to work on my mac in eclipse (plugin).

git recommendations will also be useful although i haven't tried it yet.

since there is only a small team of developers I would prefer a cheaper/free solution (advanced features like merging are not necessary)

Thanks

Comment: [Installing Subclipse on Mac OS X](http://www.temme.net/sander/2007/11/26/subclipse-on-macosx/) or [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) (however, not free).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting thing with Git is that you don't need to install anything:
Just download one of the [latest Eclipse distributions](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), and you will have **[EGit plugin](http://eclipse.org/egit/)** already included in that Eclipse.

Since it is a DVCS, there is no notion of "client" or "server": your repo will be local and will include the full history.

[image: egit repo]